# Performing a data migration that cannot be expressed in SQL easily or at all

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I have an object with a `Name` property which I have to split to `First` and `Last`.

From what I can see, there's no opportunity to construct a `DbContext` during a migration and change data. I also can't find a good way to do this in SQL (except a stored procedure which is beyond my expertise).

Is there an automatic way to do this (given a function that has the logic for splitting the name)?

I thought about adding `First` and `Last` in one migration and then removing `Name` in another but I can't find a hook to perform the update between them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It has to be some sort of a target database specific DML / DDL construct like SQL command, batch, block etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's sad. I guess the schema for the context would be invalid if caught mid migration

Answer (score 0):

You may have to perform 2 separate migrations. The first one as you suggest would add First and Last (and in the Seed function of the configuration file you can update the values in the database to reflect your changes).

Then the second migration can then remove the Name field.

Would something like that work for you?

Comment: It still requires a manual step. The Seed function that you describe would have to be deleted after removing the Name attribute and the changes committed, at which point this migration would no longer be possible. So for each database migrated, someone has to checkout the code at the first migration commit, run the first migration, seed, then update the code and repeat. Oh well!

Comment: What if you wrote actual sql in the seed function, so you can check (with exists keyword) if the Name field is present or not?